# timestamp column is not in ISO 8601 format

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datetime-format

I want all the dates from the server to be sent in the **ISO 8601** standard in Laravel. Laravel version is 9. The `created_at` and `updated_at` columns are sent in the wanted format but my custom column is not in that format.

Here is the code of the Seeder

```
"questions_updated_at" => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
"updated_at" => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Also tested with `now()`
In MySQL their values are same. Migration

```
$table->timestamp("questions_updated_at");
$table->timestamps();
```

In the Model. `protected $dateFormat = \DateTime::ISO8601;`

In Controller `return response(MyClass::where('show_on_front', true)->get());`

And in Postman getting it like this.

```
[{
   "questions_updated_at": "2022-11-16 15:02:44",
   "created_at": "2022-11-16T15:02:44.000000Z",
   "updated_at": "2022-11-16T15:02:44.000000Z"
}]
```

In `app.php` the time zone is `'timezone' => 'UTC'`
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use casts in order to change the type of the data fetched from the data,

#### in the model file

```
protected $casts = [
   'questions_updated_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

the timestamp is stored as timestamp and it is fetched as string from database , casts is used to change it to the prefered DateTime format , the created_at and updated_at are already casted in `HasAtttributes` trait

Comment: But now it is not working in join. The `questions_updated_at` is still the same.
`$compQuizzes = DB::table("composite_quizzes as cq")
->where("class_id", $myClass->id)
->join('my_classes as mc', "mc.id", "=", "cq.class_id")
->select("cq.*", "mc.class_name", "mc.questions_updated_at")
->get();`

Comment: I think you ll have to do a selectRaw instead of select and then format the date , try somthin like this : 
`->selectRaw("cq.* , mc.class_name, DATE_FORMAT(mc.questions_updated_at, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') as questions_updated_at") ->get();`